# A question about query result judgement in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Code as follows:

```
$db = DatabaseService::getInstance();     //get a database handle,base on pdo
$sql = "select * from authusers where ssouid = '".$ssouid."' order by regtime";
$res = $db->query($sql);

if($res && $res->fetch())   // here is the Problem line
{
  //do something
}
else
{
  //raise some exception
}
```

In the problem line,I want the condition to find out whether some record(s) in database has been fetched or not.But I found somehow it didn't always work.Someone suggested me to use `select count(*) as num ...` to do this ,but I think that would be some kinda of duplicate query as `select * from...`.

Comment: We don't know exactly what is in the Database class, so I don't think we can really help...

Comment: Databaseserver class is based on PDO:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also work because query made its way to db:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($res))   // here is the Problem line
{
  //do something
}
else
{
  //raise some exception
}
```

Comment: @Justin Johnson: you are right, initially i though that but then did not do :)